# CNAME for top of domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

Is it possible to set a CNAME record at the top of a domain? (i.e. `@ CNAME www`, `@ CNAME foobar.com.`, etc.)

My ISP says that it's only possible to use CNAME's for subdomains but I've read somewhere else that is should be possible even if not recommended.

Comment: I want to point a top-level-domain to a amazon cloudfront distribution and they only support cnames.

Comment: I should point out that EVERY domain is a "subdomain".  `example.com` is a subdomain of `com`, and `com` is a subdomain of `.`.  Any limitations put in place by your ISP are put in place by your ISP and perhaps the registrar, not by the underlying technology.

Comment: example.com is *not* a top level domain so your question requires a rephrasing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't a CNAME record be used at the apex (aka root) of a domain?](http://serverfault.com/questions/613829/why-cant-a-cname-record-be-used-at-the-apex-aka-root-of-a-domain)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Not possible - this would conflict with the SOA- and NS-records at the domain root.

From RFC1912 section 2.4:
             "A CNAME record is not allowed to coexist with any other data."

Comment: The quoted text doesn't say that it's not possible, only that it can't be used with other records. Your NS and SOA records would reside with the canonical name.

Comment: Just a side note, RFC1912 is Informational and does not define a standard of any sort. [RFC2181 has Proposed Standard status](http://serverfault.com/a/613830/152073) and is a better link for unambiguously forbidding this behavior.

Answer (score 5):

You can setup your domain to be a CNAME to another domain, but then *everything* will go to that other domain -- including mail and the SOA "start-of-authority" record itself. However, you can still have separate subdomains, like "private.domain.com" use another mail and web server.

Comment: If the parent zone has `NS` records and the child "zone" is only a CNAME then some systems will get _very_ confused.

Comment: This is implementation specific and dangerous advice. **Don't CNAME @, ever.**

Answer (score 0):

I use cloudflare to setup CNAME for root domain and it works fine..
without breaking the mail records

Comment: No, you didn't. It doesn't work that way.

Comment: @ChrisS [CloudFlare has a nasty hack](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169056-CNAME-Flattening-RFC-compliant-support-for-CNAME-at-the-root). It seems to work, though.

Comment: I don't think they even use a hack, I think they just point the domain to a common set of RRs. I do the same thing with BIND zone files (use the same zone for half of my domains). I think the only "hack" is that they use the term CNAME in there.

Comment: I don't think the implementation details are relevant - the point of  the answer appears to be that cloudflare allows you to define a CNAME record for the root domain, which it does, and corroborates `I've read somewhere else that is should be possible` (though that wouldn't have been true in 2010).

Comment: @AD7six If an actual CNAME record existed at the apex, it would be a RFC2181 violation. As it stands, this is a case of confusing record synthesis that has no basis in a standard defining RFC. (the fake `ANAME` and `ALIAS` records are more honest) If I'm wrong and a standard defining RFC does define the behavior for flattening an apex CNAME I'm all ears, but I'm extremely skeptical of this given RFC2181.