# Circumvent ID10T domain parking after MyDomain software migration?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, cname-record, dns-hosting

I have been a happy customer of MyDomain.com, which handles domain stuff for http://JonathansCorner.com, which is my personal site handled correctly and http://JonathanHayward.com, which is CNAMEd to http://JonathansCorner.com where it normally serves up a professional site, but now serves up an imitation domain name speculator site because MyDomain includes free parking service and this parking trumps CNAMEs, with some dumbed-down menu choices that do not have information scent for "I made a CNAME choice; please respect it."

Most of my domains are CNAMEd, usually referring to the server with my personal site.

What should I do now? Manual override for each CNAMEd domain? Re-evaluate my provider? Add more detail to the support ticket (it says that CNAMEd domains have CNAME trumped by parking)? Decide it's time for a service that drapes slightly dirty pictures of girls?

With MyDomain for NOW...

Comment: It looks fine to me. I just went to both sites.

Comment: Hrm? <http://JonathansCorner.com> pulls as intended; <http://JonathanHayward.com> pulls Jonathanhayward.com
November 22, 2012 
Related Searches

Hayward
Online School
Donate A Car
Jonathan
Tires
Bill Payment
Life Insurance Quote
Pay Traffic Ticket
Medical Assistant
Payday Loan Online

Sponsored Listings

HAYWARD AT AMAZON.COM
Buy Hayward at Amazon! Qualified orders over $25 ship free
Amazon.com
PONTOON RENTALS $795WK-UP
New-60-90HP Honda-20'-25' Luxury-Free Delv- Round Lk-your dock-Chippewa
www.laketimeboats.com/
HAYWARD POOL PUMPS
Hayward Swimming Pool and Spa Pumps. Inyo Lowest Price Guar...

Comment: P.S. I do not sell pool-related hardware. I'm an author and IT professional; <http://JonathanHayward.com> is intended to sell my professional services and to a slight degree my books. Did you see copy like I pasted above, or did you see a professional site with my picture and links to open source projects and the like?

Comment: @joeqwerty it look broken to me.  But the record is also broken.  Perhaps your DNS resolver is more forgiving?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/430970/cname-for-top-level-domain

Comment: MY bad, sorry. I didn't pay attention to the content. I saw a link to helpdesk software and a link to Amazon and assumed that was the correct site. Apologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is **not** valid to have a CNAME at the top level.  By setting one you have probably broken you zone.

You cannot use a CNAME for `jonathanhayward.com`.

Comment: Switched to an A record; thanks and +1.