# How does this main domain have a CNAME record?

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

I was under the impression that only subdomains could have CNAME records: main domains need to define all their own records. However, `apt-get.com` seems to have only a CNAME record. How can this work?

```
$ dig apt-get.com 

; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> apt-get.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 45743
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 9, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;apt-get.com.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
apt-get.com.        86336   IN  CNAME   thie5ku9.dsgeneration.com.
thie5ku9.dsgeneration.com. 60   IN  A   208.73.211.242
thie5ku9.dsgeneration.com. 60   IN  A   208.73.211.246
thie5ku9.dsgeneration.com. 60   IN  A   208.73.211.166
thie5ku9.dsgeneration.com. 60   IN  A   208.73.211.232
thie5ku9.dsgeneration.com. 60   IN  A   208.73.211.161
thie5ku9.dsgeneration.com. 60   IN  A   208.73.210.233
thie5ku9.dsgeneration.com. 60   IN  A   208.73.211.186
thie5ku9.dsgeneration.com. 60   IN  A   208.73.211.188

;; Query time: 59 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Jun 10 15:05:48 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 193


$ dig apt-get.com ns

; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> apt-get.com ns
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 43831
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;apt-get.com.           IN  NS

;; Query time: 26 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Jun 10 15:12:37 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 29


$ dig apt-get.com ns @b.gtld-servers.net

; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> apt-get.com ns @b.gtld-servers.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 38228
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 2
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;apt-get.com.           IN  NS

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
apt-get.com.        172800  IN  NS  ns1.domainrecover.com.
apt-get.com.        172800  IN  NS  ns2.domainrecover.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.domainrecover.com.  172800  IN  A   66.45.232.66
ns2.domainrecover.com.  172800  IN  A   65.23.159.179

;; Query time: 70 msec
;; SERVER: 192.33.14.30#53(192.33.14.30)
;; WHEN: Tue Jun 10 15:07:05 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 111
```

The domain does resolve. I get the following headers:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Testing_Sniffer/4.15
Host: apt-get.com
Accept: */*

HTTP/1.0 200 (OK)
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, must-revalidate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Oversee Turing v1.0.0
Content-Length: 1347
Content-Type: text/html
Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=3, max=96
P3P: policyref="http://www.dsparking.com/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="NOI DSP COR ADMa OUR NOR STA"
Set-Cookie: parkinglot=1; domain=.apt-get.com; path=/; expires=Wed, 11-Jun-2014 14:10:37 GMT
```

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<!-- turing_cluster_prod -->
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>apt-get.com</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="apt-get.com" />
    <meta name="description" content="apt-get.com" />
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
    <meta name="revisit-after" content="10" />


    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /> 



    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.cookie = "jsc=1";
    </script>

  </head>
  <frameset rows="100%,*" frameborder="no" border="0" framespacing="0">
    <frame src="http://apt-get.com?epl=5PfLSSqWrYDAt-gbwMDK_rA3b1UJCYVTJHfxTzr9FTDQV84b6vAgVhU3FTeCRQNiuRNv79Ni0V3mkEVNRhpqo2gpMjp5iOIR1w2_EISPENaqzoXohVXl2QI3ryXlRCB4FaIIaxynnWXWY6QBgBgNiIZ6agD1NBoNGg0ajXpUCXUAIJDer78AAOB_AwAAQIDbCwAAe_NWlVlTJllBMTZoWkKPAAAA8A" name="apt-get.com">
  </frameset>
  <noframes>
    <body><a href="http://apt-get.com?epl=5PfLSSqWrYDAt-gbwMDK_rA3b1UJCYVTJHfxTzr9FTDQV84b6vAgVhU3FTeCRQNiuRNv79Ni0V3mkEVNRhpqo2gpMjp5iOIR1w2_EISPENaqzoXohVXl2QI3ryXlRCB4FaIIaxynnWXWY6QBgBgNiIZ6agD1NBoNGg0ajXpUCXUAIJDer78AAOB_AwAAQIDbCwAAe_NWlVlTJllBMTZoWkKPAAAA8A">Click here to go to apt-get.com</a>.</body>
  </noframes>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CNAME for top of domain?](http://serverfault.com/questions/430970/cname-for-top-of-domain)

Comment: I'm not sure it's a complete duplicate - the leading and accepted answer for that says it's "*not possible*", which is clearly untrue - hence this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You misunderstand the nature of RFCs.  Anyone is perfectly free to violate them, but unpredictable behaviour may result.  You are seeing a perfect example of that: when you ask for `NS` records for the domain from a `.com` server, you get one answer (a pair of records), but when you do it through normal recursion, you get a different result (`SERVFAIL`).

Resolution of the domain name works, as you'd expect (there is a CNAME in place, after all), but it would be very hard to do **anything** else with that domain (no mail, no `www.` server) in a reliable way.

You have posted a perfect example of why violating the RFCs is unwise.

Comment: Indeed, because the word `should` is used in RFC 1034 I suppose a more proper answer to [the other question](http://serverfault.com/questions/430970/cname-for-top-of-domain) would be "Any sane DNS server will tell you that you can't do that, but an insane one will let you do whatever you want, to your endless detriment."

Answer (score -3):

This is actually a valid use of a CNAME. You can use a CNAME on the apex of a DNS zone, but you can't use it alongside any other record types, such as MX. This is an unacceptable trade-off for most domain owners, but it is used from time to time.

Comment: Don't confuse "it works currently" with "it's valid".

Comment: [RFC1034](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1034): `If a CNAME RR is present at a node, no other data should be present`, [RFC1035](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1035): `Exactly one SOA RR should be present at the top of the zone.`, etc.