# Mandrill, AWS, Namecheap, SPF missing domain error

Tags: amazon-web-services, spf, mandrill

I'm trying to setup a Sending Domain on Mandrill but I get a SPF missing error.

My APP is running on AWS, I'm using EC2 and Elastic Beanstalk, and my domain is on Namecheap.

DNS are setup as follow:

> CNAME Record @ 'my-instance-id'.elasticbeanstalk.com.
>
> TXT Record @ v=spf1 include:spf.mandrillapp.com ?all
>
> TXT Record @ v=DKIM1; k=rsa;
>   p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCrLHiExVd55zd/IQ/J/mRwSRMAocV/hMB3jXwaHH36d9NaVynQFYV8NaWi69c1veUtRzGt7yAioXqLj7Z4TeEUoOLgrKsn8YnckGs9i3B3tVFB+Ch/4mPhXWiNfNdynHWBcPcbJ8kjEQ2U8y78dHZj1YeRXXVvWob2OaKynO8/lQIDAQAB;
>
> URL Redirect Record www https://myapp.com Permanent (301)

This morning I was able to verify SPF address, and I started to have SPF missing error after updating my DNS with the CNAME entry (actually I just moved my app to AWS).

Any idea on how I can fix this? Thank you!

## EDIT

The answer from Mandrill support:

> Thanks for writing in. It looks like your "myapp.com" domain is a
>   CNAME to "myapp.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com". This can make
>   things tricky because in DNS you can't have two records (a TXT-type,
>   and a CNAME-type) with the same name. As a result, you won't be able
>   to set up SPF for "myapp.com". Furthermore, with the way CNAMEs
>   redirect, theoretically it would be possible to set up SPF records at
>   the final destination where those redirects lead to, but
>   unfortunately, Mandrill's SPF and DKIM validator is overly-specific
>   and as such isn't able to verify DNS records for domains that CNAMEs
>   to another domain. Given these limitations, the only real option is to
>   change your "myapp.com" from a CNAME to an A record pointing directly
>   at the IP address at the end of that CNAME chain. You should then be
>   able to set up SPF for this domain.

Actually I'm not sure I've such IP available to point at.. didyou solve similar issue? Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CNAME for top of domain?](http://serverfault.com/questions/430970/cname-for-top-of-domain)

Comment: @chicks - it's not duplicate, my question is strictly related to AWS and Mandrill setup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `CNAME` can't have other records alongside it. A request for TXT (or anything else like MX, A, etc.) records will follow the `CNAME` and receive `my-instance-id.elasticbeanstalk.com.`'s `TXT` records (if any) instead.

Using Route53's `ALIAS` record type instead of a `CNAME` is the recommended solution. The `ALIAS` looks like a normal `A` record to the outside world, but reflects IP address changes to the Elastic Beanstalk instance automatically.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/01/aws-elastic-beanstalk-adds-support-for-amazon-route-53-aliasing/

Comment: You are right I actually used an ALIAS

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem and I was able to verify my sending domain in Mandrill.

I told namecheap to use AWS nameservers, then on AWS Route53 I setup an A Record to point to AWS EB instance, and then added the TXT records necessary for Mandrill domain validation directly in AWS.

Hope this might help others with same issue.

Comment: You could use an A record with GoDaddy too, but note that an A record isn't what you want here. If the Elastic Beanstalk instance gets replaced due to a scaling event or a server outage, the new instance will have a new IP and your record will no longer work. See my answer for the recommended approach.