# adding txt record for domain verification

Tags: dns-zone

I would like to verify ownership of my domain by adding TXT record.
For that i have two set of values 
1)TXT Record Name: _acme-challenge.cooloffers.in
Value: M6ozS9PeCBZ-Q1sw4mBuJ3tsbuLQTMAkISHF--noe0k

TXT Record Name: _acme-challenge.www.cooloffers.in
Value: 7jeD7BMCmB5ksXIi7QYmp3gC6lGv-_E1s-ZW2mUNjKQ

I just have to add those values from DNS Zone, then it will return via the
function dns_get_record("cooloffers.in"); ?

How we can verify after adding those pair of values?

Comment: I can see your TXT record.  `dig txt sadsad.cooloffers.in` returns `sadsad.cooloffers.in.   3600    IN      TXT     "@"`.  If that isn't what you wanted to know, could you edit your question to be a bit more, well, coherent?

Comment: just made an edit, please check.

Answer (score 0):

The standard tool for checking DNS records is `dig`, which tells me that your first `TXT` record is being propagated, but the value is wrong:

```
[me@risby logs]$ dig txt _acme-challenge.cooloffers.in
[...]
;; ANSWER SECTION:
_acme-challenge.cooloffers.in. 3600 IN  TXT     "n5tDWoEdtXV_fF8Xv52eyyhbv03cIv3o2FPMFBHjtEA "
```

The second one isn't:

```
[me@risby logs]$ dig txt _acme-challenge.www.cooloffers.in
[...]
;; ANSWER SECTION:
_acme-challenge.www.cooloffers.in. 3600 IN CNAME cooloffers.in.
```

The reason the second one isn't working is that you've put a `CNAME` record on the node, and [that precludes any other resource record from being advertised on that node](https://serverfault.com/questions/430970/cname-for-top-of-domain/430971#430971).